# Is there a way I can put a hotkey to type alt codes faster?

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, hotkeys

I want to know if there's a way to type alt codes faster, like setting a hotkey. For example, replacing * with ”. I'm not that good with technology, and if this is the wrong website for this, please tell me so.

Comment: You can replace text using [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com), if you are on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what it is you're trying to do. But if you're trying to remap a key / make a hotkey, i would recommend using [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). It is simple programming (although, it can do slightly more complex things) and will most likely help you accomplish whatever it is you're trying to do.